# Which F1 driver has won races at the most tracks?

Tags: formula-1

I know that Lewis Hamilton has more than 100 wins, but how many different tracks has he won at? And is he the driver that has won at the most different tracks?. For example, Lewis has won 8 times at Silverstone, but let's count as one particular track win.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at time of writing, Lewis Hamilton has won at the most different Grand Prix, as well as individual circuits - 31 for both.

**Different Grand Prix** [(source)](https://www.statsf1.com/en/statistiques/pilote/victoire/grandprix-different.aspx)

| Number | Grand Prix | Year of First Win | Number of Wins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Canada | 2007 | 7 |
| 2 | USA | 2007 | 6 |
| 3 | Hungary | 2007 | 8 |
| 4 | Japan | 2007 | 5 |
| 5 | Australia | 2008 | 2 |
| 6 | Monaco | 2008 | 3 |
| 7 | Britain | 2008 | 8 |
| 8 | Germany | 2008 | 4 |
| 9 | China | 2008 | 6 |
| 10 | Singapore | 2009 | 4 |
| 11 | Turkey | 2010 | 2 |
| 12 | Belgium | 2010 | 4 |
| 13 | Abu Dhabi | 2011 | 5 |
| 14 | Italy | 2012 | 5 |
| 15 | Malaysia | 2014 | 1 |
| 16 | Bahrain | 2014 | 5 |
| 17 | Spain | 2014 | 6 |
| 18 | Russia | 2014 | 5 |
| 19 | Austria | 2016 | 1 |
| 20 | Mexico | 2016 | 2 |
| 21 | Brazil | 2016 | 2 |
| 22 | Azerbaijan | 2018 | 1 |
| 23 | France | 2018 | 2 |
| 24 | Styria<sup>1</sup> | 2020 | 1 |
| 25 | Tuscany | 2020 | 1 |
| 26 | Eifel | 2020 | 1 |
| 27 | Portugal | 2020 | 2 |
| 28 | Emilia-Romagna | 2020 | 1 |
| 29 | São Paulo<sup>2</sup> | 2021 | 1 |
| 30 | Qatar | 2021 | 1 |
| 31 | Saudi Arabia | 2021 | 1 |

1. This was the second race held at the Red Bull Ring in Austria in a COVID-19 impacted season.
2. *Officially* the 2021 Brazilian GP was called the 2021 São Paulo Grand Prix - hence the differential between the two. Even if you count these together LH is still well clear of Schumacher, 30 to 22.

**Different Circuits** [(source)](https://www.statsf1.com/en/statistiques/pilote/victoire/circuit-different.aspx)

| Number | Circuit / Location | Year of First Win | Number of Wins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Montréal | 2007 | 7 |
| 2 | Indianapolis | 2007 | 1 |
| 3 | Hungaroring | 2007 | 8 |
| 4 | Fuji | 2007 | 1 |
| 5 | Melbourne | 2008 | 2 |
| 6 | Monaco | 2008 | 3 |
| 7 | Silverstone | 2008 | 8 |
| 8 | Hockenheim | 2008 | 3 |
| 9 | Shanghai | 2008 | 6 |
| 10 | Singapore | 2009 | 4 |
| 11 | Istanbul | 2010 | 2 |
| 12 | Spa-Francorchamps | 2010 | 4 |
| 13 | Nürburgring | 2011 | 2 |
| 14 | Yas Marina | 2011 | 5 |
| 15 | Monza | 2012 | 5 |
| 16 | Austin | 2012 | 5 |
| 17 | Kuala Lumpur | 2014 | 1 |
| 18 | Sakhir | 2014 | 5 |
| 19 | Barcelona | 2014 | 6 |
| 20 | Suzuka | 2014 | 4 |
| 21 | Sochi | 2014 | 5 |
| 22 | Spielberg | 2016 | 2 |
| 23 | Mexico City | 2016 | 2 |
| 24 | Interlagos | 2016 | 3 |
| 25 | Bakou | 2018 | 1 |
| 26 | Le Castellet | 2018 | 2 |
| 27 | Mugello | 2020 | 1 |
| 28 | Portimão | 2020 | 2 |
| 29 | Imola | 2020 | 1 |
| 30 | Losail | 2021 | 1 |
| 31 | Djeddah | 2021 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

According to [Stats F1](https://www.statsf1.com/en/statistiques/pilote/victoire/circuit-different.aspx), Lewis Hamilton does indeed hold the record for the most wins at different tracks, having won races at **31** different tracks. The next-best is Max Verstappen, who has won races at 24 different tracks.